# Extracting the values within the square braces

Tags: python, unix, awk

I have a file testfile with the set of server names as below.

```
app-server-l11[2-5].test.com
server-l34[5-8].test.com
dd-server-l[2-4].test.com
```

Can you please help in getting output to be as follow.

```
app-server-l112.test.com
app-server-l113.test.com
app-server-l114.test.com
app-server-l115.test.com
server-l345.test.com
server-l346.test.com
server-l347.test.com
server-l348.test.com
dd-server-l2.test.com
dd-server-l3.test.com
dd-server-l4.test.com
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Have you attempted the problem?

Comment: I don't mind writing one-liners for OPs, but that's a little more complicated than that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GNU awk:

```
$ awk -F"[][]" '{split($2,a,"-"); for(i=a[1];i<=a[2];i++) print $1 i $3}' file
app-server-l112.test.com
app-server-l113.test.com
app-server-l114.test.com
app-server-l115.test.com
server-l345.test.com
server-l346.test.com
server-l347.test.com
server-l348.test.com
dd-server-l2.test.com
dd-server-l3.test.com
dd-server-l4.test.com
```

- split to fields by `[` and `]` using `FS`
- use `split` the get the range start (`a[1]`) and end (`a[2]`)
- iterate the range with `for` and output

There is no checking whether there was a range or not. It could be implemented with something like: `print (NF==3 ? $1 i $3 : $1 )`.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*)\[([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\](.*)/,a){for (i=a[2]; i<=a[3]; i++) print a[1] i a[4]}' file
app-server-l112.test.com
app-server-l113.test.com
app-server-l114.test.com
app-server-l115.test.com
server-l345.test.com
server-l346.test.com
server-l347.test.com
server-l348.test.com
dd-server-l2.test.com
dd-server-l3.test.com
dd-server-l4.test.com
```

Comment: ++:This is not just an answer-is a mini awk tutorial about match function.

Answer (score 1):

Worst and ugliest example:

```
var='app-server-l11[2-5].test.com'
for i in range(int(var[(var.find('[') +1)]), int(var[(var.find("]") - 1)])+1):
     print 'app-server-l11' + str(i) + '.test.com'
```

Use your imagination!

Answer (score 1):

```
ser_nm = ['app-server-l11[2-5].test.com','server-134[5-8].test.com','dd-server-[2-4].test.com']

for nm in ser_nm:
    for i in range(int(nm[nm.find('[')+1 : nm.find('-',(nm.find('[')+1))]), int(nm[nm.find('-',(nm.find('[')+1))+1:nm.find(']')  ] )+1):
        print(nm[:nm.find('[')] + str(i) + nm[nm.find(']')+1:])
```

This will also take care of cases where server names are like this:
'server-134[52-823].test.com'

Answer (score 0):

not the best solution, but it works...

```
inp = open('input.txt', 'r+').read()
print(inp)
result= ''
for i in inp.split('\n'):
    if len(i) > 1:
        print(repr(i))
        f1 = i.find('[')
        f2 = i.find(']')+1
        b1 = i[:f1]
        b2 = i[f2:]
        ins = i[f1:f2]
        ins = ins[1:-1]
        for j in range(int(ins.split("-")[0]),int(ins.split("-")[1])+1):
            result+=b1+str(j)+b2+'\n'

outp = open('output.txt', 'w')
outp.write(result)
outp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As this sounds like a school assignment I'm going to be fairly vague.

I would use a regular expression to extract the numeric range and the rest of the address components, then use a loop to iterate over the extracted numeric range to build each address (using the other captured address components).

---

Since it's been over a week:

```
    import re

    inputs = [ "app-server-l11[2-5].test.com", "server-l34[5-8].test.com", "dd-server-l[2-4].test.com" ]

    pattern = r"\s*(?P<subdomain>[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+)\[(?P<range_start>\d+)-(?P<range_end>\d+)\](?P<domain>\S+)"

    expr = re.compile( pattern )

    def expand_domain( domain ):
        mo = expr.match( domain )
        if mo is not None:
            groups = mo.groupdict()
            subdomain = groups[ "subdomain" ]
            domain = groups[ "domain" ]
            range_start = int( groups[ "range_start" ] )
            range_end = int( groups[ "range_end" ] )
            result = [ "{}{:d}{}".format( subdomain, index, domain ) for index in range( range_start, range_end + 1 ) ]
            return result
        else:
            raise ValueError( "'{}' does not match the expected input.".format( domain ) )

    for domain in inputs:
        print( "'{}':".format( domain ) )
        for exp_dom in expand_domain( domain ):
            print( "--> {}".format( exp_dom ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command for the required output without any complex statement.

```
awk -f test.awk file.txt
```

test.awk must contains the below lines:

```
{
    if(a=match($0,"\\["))
    {
            start=strtonum(substr($0,a+1,1));
            end=strtonum(substr($0,a+3,1));
            copy=$0;
            for(i=start;i<=end;i++)
            {
                    sub("\\[[0-9]{1,}-[0-9]{1,}\\]",i,copy);
                    print copy;
                    copy = $0;
            }
    }
    else
    {
            print $0;
    }
}
```

file.txt contains your input file like below lines:

```
app-server-l11[2-5].test.com
server-l34[5-8].test.com
dd-server-l[2-4].test.com
```

output:

```
app-server-l112.test.com
app-server-l113.test.com
app-server-l114.test.com
app-server-l115.test.com
server-l345.test.com
server-l346.test.com
server-l347.test.com
server-l348.test.com
dd-server-l2.test.com
dd-server-l3.test.com
dd-server-l4.test.com
```